# how can i detect and get email notification of traffic in azure api management

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-api-management

i have question regarding Azure API Management again : ).

i am using API management which is API Gateway doing HTTPS to Azure Storage REST API directly

and is there any way that i cant get email notification when there are massive requests or high latency at response ??

Thanx for reading : )

Answer (score 0):

You can configure alert notifications either in the portal or via the REST API or .NET SDK to monitor for specific Azure Storage Metrics that you want.
See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-receive-alert-notifications/ for more details.

For massive requests, you might want to consider using "TotalRequests" or "TotalBillableRequests" in a specific time period.
For high response latency, you can track "AverageE2ELatency" or "AverageServerLatency" in a specific time period.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#monitoring-performance for more details on these specific metrics and how they relate to performance monitoring.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanx for your adivce, but i am sorry my question might be ambiguous. what i wanna know is not the storage side, API Management side.

Answer (score 0):

Sriprasad's answer makes sense for configuration from the Storage side. From the API Management side, you cannot currently set a notification on any event other than the built-in ones (subscription requests, new subscriptions, application gallery requests, new issues/comments, approaching of user subscription quota limit).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Log-To-Eventhub policy to log a message to event hub for every request and consume it in a custom or third party solution like AppInsights/Runscopee to fire an alert.

Refer
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-log-to-eventhub-sample/

Comment: Thanx for your advice, there were high latency on API management, so i moved to API App : ). and i was using Eventhub, seems like no way to catch the response time though.

Comment: @MyoungsoKang What magnitude of high latency were you seeing?  My experience is that API Management rarely adds more than 20-30 ms on top of a warm request.

Comment: well i used Jmeter to get tested and i ran 1000 threads, latency was ... which is not stable though more than seconds less than 10s.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to get report/metrics from API Management you can use the management rest api's for APIM.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn781421.aspx

Specifically you might want to look at reportByAPI (which gives you useful metrics in response like callcounts, apiTimeAvg) based on which you can setup alerts/email notification.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn781421.aspx#ReportByAPI